# cannot enable site feed feature on sharepoint 2013 enterprise wiki

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature, sitefeed

hi I cannt enable sharepoint 2013 site feed  feature on sharepoint 2013 enterprise wiki is there any solution to do that what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

**By default,** the Site Feed is included in Team Site Template but not automatically included in Enterprise Wiki Template.

> **Note:** To access Feeds, the user must have a user profile and a My Site in SharePoint Server.otherwise, you will get

```
SiteFeedFeatureReceiver: can only be enabled on the same farm where
MySites are deployed.
```

**To activate Site Feed features**

- Site settings > site features and activate the “Site Feed” feature.

---

Comment: hi how can I config profile on wiki enterprise farm  do I need to create sub site from subcategory my site ?